# How can I dynamically construct a GraphQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, graphql

I'm using the following query in GraphQL:

```
$q = "
{ 
    shop { 
        name 
    } 
}
";
```

Initially I tried to do it dynamically in PHP in the following way:

```
$fieldName = 'name';

$query = [
    "shop" => [
        $fieldName
    ]
];
```

And later on when passing the query to GraphQL I wanna convert in GraphQL suitable format.

Well I can do it by using iterative function in PHP but that doesn't seem very efficient.

```
function formatGraphQLQuery($queryArray, $indentation = 0) {
    $formattedQuery = '';
    $indent = str_repeat('    ', $indentation);

    foreach ($queryArray as $field => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $formattedQuery .= $indent . $field . " {\n";
            $formattedQuery .= formatGraphQLQuery($value, $indentation + 1);
            $formattedQuery .= $indent . "}\n";
        } else {
            $formattedQuery .= $indent . $value . "\n";
        }
    }

    return $formattedQuery;
}
```

Also using `json_encode()` doesn't work as it returns in the following format:

```
{
    "shop":[
            "name"
        ]
}
```

So what would be an idea solution?

**Note:** Just a simple example is given here to keep the question clear and concise but the actual queries will be larger containing variables, arguments and aliases.

Comment: Your query sample is easy to transform but it become tricky when you have to transform complex queries containing arguments or aliases (see https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments). In this case you may have to write a complex parser. You may consume a lot of time to write a parser that reduce the power of a plain GraphQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personnaly use HEREDOC syntax to write GraphQL queries.

HEREDOC syntax behaves like a double quote string so you can add variables in it

```
$fieldName = 'name';
$query = <<<GRAPHQL
{ 
    shop { 
        $fieldName
    } 
}
GRAPHQL;
```